# Why there is no confliction with linking libpng and opencv at the same time?

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, linker, libpng

The ios application is for png reading, and we have had opencv(with libpng) as framework. We want use libpng directly other than opencv.
What was found were: with only libpng headerfile included, we can compile and read png, while with the full libpng, i.e. also put .c file in the compile list, we can compile and read png too.
Seems that opencv framework contains the libpng implement. The problem is, why there is no error when linking with lipng source code compiled?

Answer (score 0):

When you link against a library, you do not import the whole library, but only the symbols your program expects but is missing (recursively, of course).

So since your application already provides the symbols for libpng, the linking process doesn't even try to look them up when linking opencv, since it's not missing them in the first place.

Comment: So if we have two static library, and both have the implementation of the same function , and compile the application with two libraries, no link error will be reported?